# Can't get Mojo::Redis2 to subscribe

Tags: perl, redis, mojolicious

I wrote the following program (`redis.pl`), Redis is running locally with the default port settings, but when I run `redis.pl` with `morbo redis.pl` I never get `********* 1` on the screen. Why is that? It seems the subscription never happens. How can I fix this?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use v5.18;
use warnings;

use Mojolicious::Lite;
use Mojo::Redis2;

say "Welcome";

my $redis = Mojo::Redis2->new();

$redis->subscribe(['pubsub'] => sub {
    say "********* 1";
});

get '/' => sub {
    my $self = shift;

    $self->render(json => {a => 1});
};

app->start;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a redis instance installed currently, but I think this should work.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use v5.18;
use warnings;

use Mojolicious::Lite;
use Mojo::Redis2;

say "Welcome";

helper redis => sub {state $redis = Mojo::Redis2->new()};

app->redis->subscribe(['pubsub'] => sub {
    say "********* 1";
});

get '/' => sub {
    my $self = shift;

    $self->render(json => {a => 1});
};

app->start;
```

I suspect that once the redis instance goes out of scope, you lose it and its connections.

Comment: But, why does ```my $redis = ...``` go out of scope? I thought the program execution stops at app->start, which *should* mean that ```my $redis``` is still alive.

Comment: with event loops and reactors, I wouldn't bet on it :-)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, by making sure I retain the return value of `$redis->subscribe` in a permanent variable, like so:

Instead of...

```
$redis->subscribe(['pubsub'] => sub {
    say "********* 1";
});
```

...I wrote...

```
our $subscription = $redis->subscribe(['pubsub'] => sub {
    say "********* 1";
});
```

That fixed the problem. I guess it's similar to `AnyEvent`, where the return value must stay alive.

Comment: subscribe returns the redis instance itself, so by storing it in your package variable (incorrectly named `$subscription`) you are holding a reference to the instance (as I mention in my answer).

Comment: You are correct. If I had only replaced ```my $redis =``` with ```our $redis = ```, this would have solved my problem, as well. The helper in your answer looks like an even cleaner solution.